# Div growing instead of overflow being applied

Tags: css, overflow, viewport-units

How can I prevent `main-content-inner` from growing to fit the content within it, and instead have an overflow enabled, so the size remains the same but becomes scrollable?

To be clear, the red border is just illustrating the boundary of the application - I do not expect this to change size, nor the boxes within it. When the content of the bottom-right box (`main-content-inner`) exceeds it's current size, I want everything to stay the same size but that div to become scrollable, e.g.

[image]

(Note that I've hardcoded the pixel width and height on the `main-content-inner` div for the sake of this screenshot.)

[Codepen replicating the issue](https://codepen.io/devklick/pen/JjwrrmZ).

```css
#root {
    width: 50dvw;
    height: 50dvh;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

.app {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 34px auto;
    grid-template-columns: auto;
    grid-template-areas:
        "title-bar"
        "app-layout";
}
.title-bar {
    grid-area: title-bar;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: lightgray;
}
.app-layout {
    grid-area: app-layout;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: auto;
    grid-template-columns: 240px auto;
    grid-template-areas:
        "side-bar main-content main-content";
    gap: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.side-bar {
    grid-area: side-bar;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: lightgray;
}
.main-content {
    grid-area: main-content;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.main-content-inner {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: scroll;
    background-color: lightgray;
}
```

```html
<div id="root">
  <div class="app">
    <div class="title-bar"></div>
    <div class="app-layout">
      <div class="side-bar"></div>
      <div class="main-content">
        <div class="main-content-inner">Lorem ipsum<br><br>dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.<br><br> Vivamus imperdiet ex<br><br> tempus nulla lobortis tristique <br><br>id eu purus. Integer<br><br> nec malesuada odio,<br><br> in scelerisque magna.<br><br> Praesent pellentesque justo risus<br><br>, non tempus<br><br> arcu dignissim malesuada.<br><br> Ut dictum blandit quam<br><br> sit amet varius<br><br>. In ut dui massa.</div></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you are trying to contain it all in the red box, then add "overflow: scroll;" into your  '#root'

Comment: @Woodini That's not what I'm looking for, sorry for not being clear. Updated the question with an example of the desired outcome. Thanks

Comment: @Woodini Surely it can be achieved using viewport units and percentages, like in this example? https://codepen.io/devklick/pen/eYbGemV

Comment: min-height:0 to .main-content and app-layout